# Windows 7 has intermittent USB problems, and some permanent ones

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, webcam, hub

I bought a 5M USB extenstion cable, which is powers so there is no lack of speed.

However it is essentially a USB Hub with just one port. It wouldn't work on any of the rear ports, saying no driver found. I tried it on all my other systems and it is just picked up as a generic hub. I tried another hub in the system in question, same result.

Also having the same problem with a Microsoft Life-Cam HD 3000 Webcam I just bought, however this won't won't on ANY port. Works fine on all other systems.

Other devices like flash drives etc work fine.

I tried uninstalling all of the USB controllers and root hubs in Device mananger and rebooting to no avail.

Please help me with this..

Comment: Get a different cable.  I have several very long ( greater then 5M )USB 3.0 and USB 2.0 extension cables and none of them are designed as a single port hub.  I have the same camera and it also works with these cables.

Answer (score 1):

Please reinstall your Chipset drivers or update it.